# Special IF commands excel

Tags: excel

I want to tell EXCEL:

IF A1 and A2 were different such that the larger of the two divided by the smaller of the two fell within the range of 2.8 to 3.8, THEN ...? How can I set up the IF part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=IF(A1<>A2,IF(3.8>=(MAX(A1,A2)/MIN(A1,A2)>=2.8),"Then…","Dividend not in range of 2.8-3.8"),"Numerator & Denominator are equal")
```